# Why are my firebase images not being displayed in the RecyclerView?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

JSON:

```
 people
     uid /// the actual uid of each user not a child named uid
       imageUrl
```

Below is the relevant code:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage)
    val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
    if (user != null) {
        val query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("people").child("imageUrl")

        val options = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<DataSnapshot>()
            .setQuery(query, DataSnapshot::class.java)
            .build()
        Log.d("DataSnapshot1", options.toString())


        class PhotoViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
            val photoImageView = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image_view)
        }

        val adapter = object : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataSnapshot, PhotoViewHolder>(options) {
            override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PhotoViewHolder {
                val view =
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_photo, parent, false)
                return PhotoViewHolder(view)
            }

            override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PhotoViewHolder, position: Int, model: DataSnapshot) {
                Log.d("DataSnapshot", model.toString())
                val imageUrl = model.child("imageUrl").getValue(String::class.java)
                if (imageUrl != null) {
                    Log.d("ImageUrl", imageUrl)
                    Glide.with(holder.itemView.context)
                        .load(imageUrl)
                        .into(holder.photoImageView)
                }
            }

        }

        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.cycle)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        adapter.startListening()
    }
}
```

What I know: The problem is not in the XMLs of this page or the image to be displayed on the recycler view. Also, ("ImageUrl") and "DataSnapshot" don't print out. But "DataSnapshot1" does print out.

Comment: You forgot to add method  @Override public int getItemCount()  { return list.size(); } of recycler view which returns the total number of items to be created into a recycler view.

Comment: thanks, but that is java, This is a kotlin file. I can convert it, just thought to mention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're trying to list all the items under the `people` node?

In that case, you need to update your query to:

```kotlin
val query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("people")
```

---

I don't think FirebaseUI supports `DataSnapshot` as a model class, so I would suggest creating a separate class to hold the data. I have created a `Person` class as an example:

```kotlin
data class Person(var imageUrl: String? = null)
```

And then your options  would become:

```kotlin
        val options = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Person>()
            .setQuery(query, Person::class.java)
            .build()
```

And your adapter:

```kotlin
        val adapter = object : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Person, PhotoViewHolder>(options) {
            override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PhotoViewHolder {
                val view =
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_photo, parent, false)
                return PhotoViewHolder(view)
            }

            override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PhotoViewHolder, position: Int, model: Person) {
                val imageUrl = model.imageUrl
                if (imageUrl != null) {
                    Log.d("ImageUrl", imageUrl)
                    Glide.with(holder.itemView.context)
                        .load(imageUrl)
                        .into(holder.photoImageView)
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware that you cannot use a DataSnapshot there. I tried your code. In `val imageUrl = model.child("imageUrl").getValue(String::class.java)`, it says child is unrecognized. Do I need to add a child member to the Person class? That seems weird. Also it says .load is ambiguous and matches with different load function. That is werid.

Comment: @noname87f Oops, my bad. Since `model` is now a `Person` object, you can simply call `model.imageUrl`. I've updated the code in my answer